# Have anyone tried to use Appium 1.2.0-beta.3 with Xcode 9.0 beta

Tags: appium, appium-ios, xcode9, xcode9-beta

I installed appium 1.2.0-beta.3 and XCode 9 , appium throws error as "[XCUITest] Error: Xcode version 9.0 is not yet supported"

Xcode: 9-beta Appium: 1.2.0-beta.3

I checked in forums but it seems both are compatible, so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Download latest version of Appium which is appium 1.7-beta , that is compatible with XCode-9

First uninstall

```
 npm -g uninstall appium@1.2.0-beta.3

 npm -g install appium@beta
```